# Dimensions must be equal issue

Tags: python, keras, loss-function, autoencoder, custom-dimensions

I created an Autoencoder model to minimise a PAPR and BER metrics in the same time i use Categorical Cross entropy for BER and a function 'PAPRLoss' for PAPR reduction i have a problem with the shapes

```
def paprLoss(y_true, y_pred):
sigR = tf.math.real(y_pred)
sigI = tf.math.imag(y_pred)
sigR = tf.reshape(sigR,(1,(72*btch)))
sigI = tf.reshape(sigI,(1,(72*btch)))
sigRI = tf.concat((sigR, sigI), 0)
yPower = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(sigRI), axis=-1))
yMax = K.max(yPower, axis=-1)
yMean = K.mean(yPower, axis=-1)
yPAPR = 10 * tf.experimental.numpy.log10(yMax/yMean)
return yMax

#generating data of size N
N = 1024000
label = np.random.randint(M,size=N)

# creating one hot encoded vectors
data = []
for i in label:
    temp = np.zeros(M)
    temp[i] = 1
    data.append(temp)    
data = np.array(data)

n_channel=2
R = k/n_channel

input_signal = Input(shape=(M,))
encoded = Dense(10*M, activation='relu')(input_signal)
encoded1 = Dense(10*M, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded1 = Dense(n_channel, activation='linear')(encoded1)
encoded2=Lambda(lambda x:x / K.sqrt(K.mean(x**2)))(encoded1)#Average Power constraint
encoded3 = Lambda(lambda x: OFDM_mod(x, Mfft, CP))(encoded2)
SNRdB_train = 55
SNR_Linear = 10**(SNRdB_train/10)
encoded51 = Lambda(lambda x: OFDM_demod(x, Mfft, CP))(encoded3)
decoded0 = Dense(10*M,activation='relu')(encoded51)
decoded = Dense(10*M,activation='relu')(decoded0)
decoded1 = Dense(M, activation='softmax')(decoded)

autoencoder= Model(inputs=input_signal, outputs=[decoded1,encoded3], name="PAPRnet_Encoder")

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adamax', loss=['categorical_crossentropy',paprLoss],loss_weights=[1.0,0.1], metrics=['accuracy'])
print (autoencoder.summary())

#training phase
history=autoencoder.fit(data, [data,data],
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=btch*Mfft,
                validation_freq=1,)
```

**I got the following error. Shapes of y_true and y_pred are not equal**

```
Dimensions must be equal, but are 512000 and 8000 for '{{node Equal_1}} = Equal[T=DT_INT64, incompatible_shape_error=true](ArgMax_2, ArgMax_3)' with input shapes: [512000], [8000].
```

Comment: this means that you shape of inputs does not match the shape of labels. You have basically too many inputs but no labels for them.  So you have 512000 images but only 8000 of them are labelled. so you would need to add all those missing labels

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont work with images but with one-hot vectors.